# Determine category of sentence

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface

I have a list of Books with Title and Organization.
I would like to get the category of each book.
Category list is predefined and choose one of them.

Books
Title 1: Agriculturalpolicy and the decisions ofagriculturalproducers as to income and investment
Organization 1: Western Agricultural Economics Association

Categories: Agriculture, Engineering, Healthcare

Can I find the category of the Book using Python?

I tried using Transformers from HuggingFace but I don't have predefined data to train or evaluate.

I am not sure whether there is an existing solution or not.

Comment: You would have to come up with the keywords that would identify books from each category.  That kind of list isn't going to exist anywhere.

Comment: If the categories are well distinct, zero-shot classification can be used without training or specifying keywords. Check out this introductory page:https://huggingface.co/tasks/zero-shot-classification

Comment: @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87 This is exactly I want. Could you answer? love to accept.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Asking for recommendations might not be appropriate on the Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but it might be possible to ask the question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Also, logging it on https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76949597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the categories are well distinct, zero-shot classification can be used without training or specifying keywords.

Check out this [introductory page](http://huggingface.co/tasks/zero-shot-classification).